# Add dynamic value to menu in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I want to add link to left navigation on user dashboard.I can add static link using this code :

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="pmembers"><name>sellermessages</name><path>social/members/20/messages/</path>
          <label>Social Settings</label></action>
```

But i want to set the `20` dynamically.How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Helper to do that.

Create a module (or use an existing one) and create a Helper

```
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Helper_Dynamic extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    function dynamicParameter() {
        // implement logic to determine parameter
        $dynamic = 20;
        return "social/members/" . $dynamic . "/messages";
    }

}
```

and in the layout update file use

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="pmembers">
    <name>sellermessages</name>
    <path helper="yourmodule/dynamic/dynamicParameter" />
    <label>Social Settings</label>
</action>
```